# set up the initial guess values for curve_fit based on I/O

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, non-linear-regression

I am new in optimization and would like to write code that will determine the values of `a1, a2, b1, b2` for a predefined function `f_model` based on the available inputs `X1_data` `X2_data` and output `Y_list`.

The code will be used on multiple datasets with available I/O and must meet 3 constraints:

1. Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm must be used i.e., `curve_fit(..., method='lm',...)` (based on scipy documentation `bounds` can not be used with `method='lm'`)
2. `1 < b1 < a1 < a2 < b2`
3. `y=((a2+(a1-a2)/(1+((x1/x2/b2)**b1)))*x2)/1000`

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f_model(x_data, b1, a1, a2, b2):
    x1, x2 = x_data
    if 1 < b1 < a1 < a2 < b2:
        return 1e-3 * (a2 + (a1 - a2) / (1 + ((x1 / x2 / b2) ** b1))) * x2
    else:
        return np.inf

X1_data = ...
X2_data = ...
Y_list = ...
X_axis = [i + 1 for i in range(X1_data.shape[0])]

for Y_data in Y_list:
    Y_data = np.array(Y_data)
#    if np.min(Y_data) > 1:
#        b1_guess = 1.01
#        a1_guess = np.min(Y_data)
#        a2_guess = np.max(Y_data) * 10
#        b2_guess = np.mean(X1_data / X2_data)
#        guess = [b1_guess, a1_guess, a2_guess, b2_guess]
#    else:
#        guess = [1.01, 100.0, 700.0, 10000.0]
    guess = [3.5, 100.0, 7300.00, 30000.00]

#    bounds = ([1.0, guess[0], guess[1], guess[2]], [np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf])
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(f_model, (X1_data, X2_data), Y_data, p0=guess, method='lm', maxfev=5000)
    print(f"Guess {guess}")
    print(f"Optimal {popt}")
    optimal_curve = f_model((X1_data, X2_data), *popt)
    plt.scatter(X_axis, Y_data, label='Data')
    plt.plot(X_axis, optimal_curve, label='Fitted Curve')

plt.xlabel('x-axis')
plt.ylabel('y-axis')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The problem is that I couldn't figure out how to properly set the values for `guess` based on I/O. By changing the values of `guess`, I got several `popt`, from which it is difficult to determine the optimal one.

I have **dataset1** to validate the code (the values of `a1, a2, b1, b2` are known). Whenever I try different combinations of `guess`, the curve fits the data well but `popt` does not provide `b1=3.98; a1=98.4; a2=7337.03; b2=29404.80`.

If anyone could help me edit the code so that for **dataset1**, `popt` will be `b1 = 3.98; a1 = 98.4; a2 = 7337.03; b2 = 29404.80`. I will be happy!

ps. As soon as, code will be validated, I would like to use it for **dataset2** as well.

**dataset1** *Y_list updated (13/12/2023)*

```
X1_data = np.array([2894648.773, 3157919.698, 3474257.841, 3800193.356, 4156493.087, 4590298.639, 5042658.177])
X2_data = np.array([67.28579923, 69.52170573, 71.68019425, 73.68463411, 75.5179478, 77.1563269, 78.52232434])
Y_list = [[411.1179, 441.5084, 471.0992, 497.1712, 520.8332, 542.983, 560.8622]]
b1=3.98; a1=98.4; a2=7337.03; b2=29404.80
```

**dataset2**

```
X1_data = np.array([240228, 259164, 267785, 300530, 339812])
X2_data = np.array([32.188719, 32.710433, 33.243463, 33.80985, 34.353048])
Y_list = [[23.79969728, 25.34667811, 26.88872834, 30.86784396, 34.04270604],
          [2.70371836, 3.33359208, 3.49283256, 3.9231444, 4.55001784],
          [0.65156594, 0.66139181, 0.50957883, 0.46295474, 0.51407824]]
```

Comment: Since you want to place a constraint on your parameters, and it is not a simple box constraint, I would say that this problem is too complicated to solve with `curve_fit()`. I think you should use `scipy.optimize.minimize()`, which is slightly more flexible, and supports the use of arbitrary constraints on parameters.

Comment: Also, you wrote that "If anyone could help me edit the code so that for dataset1, popt will be...". Why do you expect that to be the optimal solution to the nonlinear least squares problem? The sum of the squares of residuals with those parameters is ~1003, whereas the sum of the squares of residuals with the output of `curve_fit` is ~1.8 (lower). `curve_fit` happens to satisfy your constraint, too, so it seems to produce a better fit. Can you clarify why you expect that output?

Comment: @Matt Haberland, because `Y_list` of the **dataset1** have been obtained using the values `3.98, 98.4, 7337.03, 29404.80` under the above mentioned 3 constraints. Unfortunately, other details are unknown, I'm going to rebuild the code using `scipy` to find the desired outputs for other datasets.
ps. After your comment I realized that I was using the wrong `Y_list` for **dataset1**, I updated the question.

Comment: I see. With this new data, the values of `popt` returned by `curve_fit` are the same as the guess; in other words, `curve_fit` fails to perform the optimization. As you wrote, "The problem is that I couldn't figure out how to properly set the values for guess based on I/O." So mostly your question is about how to come up with a good enough guess so that `curve_fit` succeeds? I think that is more of an art than a science. You could try solving this probably with `differential_evolution` or another global optimizer if you have trouble coming up with a good guess - but they will require bounds.

Comment: Still, even when you provide a good enough guess, e.g. `[3.5, 4, 7300.00, 30000.00]` (where I've only changed element one element from `3.5` to `4`), and `curve_fit` is able to solve the problem, it still returns a different result from what you expected - one with a lower value of the objective function. The objective function is `lambda x_data, y_data, *args: np.sum((f_model(x_data, *args) - y_data)**2)`; if you are trying to minimize something different, you'll need to specify that in the problem statement. Your values just don't minimize that function.